# Having trouble with Perl script that converts XML to hash

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script to convert the XML file below into a hash:

```
<university>
   <name>svu</name>
  <location>ravru</location>
 <branch>
  <electronics>
 <student name="xxx" number="12">
 <semester number="1"subjects="7" rank="2"/>
 </student>
 <student name="xxx" number="15">
 <semester number="1" subjects="7" rank="10"/>
 <semester number="2" subjects="4" rank="1"/>
  </student>
   <student name="xxx" number="16">
   <semester number="1"subjects="7" rank="2"/>
  <semester number="2"subjects="4" rank="2"/>
   </student>
</electronics>
  </branch>
   </university>.
          . 
          .
          .
          .
          .
<data>
  <student name="msr" number="1" branch="computers" />
   <student name="ksr" number="2" branch="electronics" />
  <student name="lsr" number="3" branch="EEE" />
  <student name="csr" number="4" branch="IT" />
   <student name="msr" number="5" branch="MEC" />
  <student name="ssr" number="6" branch="computers" />
  <student name="msr" number="1" branch="CIV" />
  .............................
   ..............................
    .....................
 </data>
```

How can I create a hash table for the data elements, with the name and number as the key and branch is the value in that hash. I need this because some students have the same name and some students have same number.

By using this hash key I have to search in the university node for student if found and print the branch name of each student.

I written some script in `XML::Simple` but am not able to create a hash.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;
 use Data::Dumper; 
 use XML::Simple;

 my $xml = new XML::Simple;
 my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml", forcearray => [ 'student' , 'semister' ],
                                    KeyAttr    => { student  => "+Name"  } );

 print Dumper($data);
```

by using data dumper I am printing hole xml information. but I need to print only Data Node elements only please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write my own `XML::Parser` handler to combine attributes into key values (if that's something supported by `XML::Simple` I couldn't find it in the docs).  This example should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

sub tag_start { my ($expat, $tagname) = (shift, shift);
    # attributes are now in @_
    my %a = grep { $_=$_=>shift } @_; # attribute hash for this tag
    my $context = join('/',$expat->context()) || '';

    if ($context eq 'xml/data') {
        if ($tagname eq 'student') {
            push @{($hash{"$a{name}:$a{number}"}||=[])}, $a{branch};
        }
    } elsif ($context eq ...) {
        ...
    }
}
my $p = new XML::Parser(Handlers => { Start=>\&tag_start });
$p->parsefile('file.xml');
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Note that to get this to work I had to clean up your XML a bit by enclosing it in an `<xml>` tag and adding some missing spaces:

```
<xml>
    <university>
        <name>svu</name>
        <location>ravru</location>
        <branch>
            <electronics>
                <student name="xxx" number="12">
                    <semester number="1" subjects="7" rank="2"/>
                </student>
                <student name="xxx" number="15">
                    <semester number="1" subjects="7" rank="10"/>
                    <semester number="2" subjects="4" rank="1"/>
                </student>
                <student name="xxx" number="16">
                    <semester number="1" subjects="7" rank="2"/>
                    <semester number="2" subjects="4" rank="2"/>
                </student>
            </electronics>
        </branch>
    </university>
    <data>
        <student name="msr" number="1" branch="computers" />
        <student name="ksr" number="2" branch="electronics" />
        <student name="lsr" number="3" branch="EEE" />
        <student name="csr" number="4" branch="IT" />
        <student name="msr" number="5" branch="MEC" />
        <student name="ssr" number="6" branch="computers" />
        <student name="msr" number="1" branch="CIV" />
    </data>
</xml>
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ksr:2' => [
                     'electronics'
                   ],
          'msr:1' => [
                     'computers',
                     'CIV'
                   ],
          'csr:4' => [
                     'IT'
                   ],
          'ssr:6' => [
                     'computers'
                   ],
          'msr:5' => [
                     'MEC'
                   ],
          'lsr:3' => [
                     'EEE'
                   ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `XML::Simple` and `XML::Fast` together. Both perform essentially the same thing.

Invoking multiple XML parsers for the same functionality invites trouble in the form of undesired behavior, code that should work but doesn't and debugging that will leave you holding your hands in your head because identically-named methods are treading on one another's toes.

---

I'd stick with `XML::Fast` for this case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Fast;

my $data = xml2hash 'data.xml', array => [ 'student', 'semester' ];
```

Even if the structure is not exactly the desired one, `$data` can easily be post-processed and seasoned to taste (it is a data structure after all).

Comment: I need to create hash for data node elements not for student and semester. can you suggest me how to create hash, in that name and number as keys and branch as values.